# Key error: column not found...but its there

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to group months together and then create a count column so I can graph it later. However, I keep receiving the following error

> KeyError: 'Column not found: Count'

I don't understand why I'm receiving this error when I clearly have a column named count in the dataframe. Here is my code thus far:

```
df = df[['DATE', 'Count']]

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

df['DATE'].groupby(df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%B'))['Count'].agg('count')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subsetting the dataframe by using only `df['DATE']`. So this subset will not have `Count` column. Hence when you apply groupby here, it gives you `Keyerror` with `Count`.

So replace the following command:

```
df['DATE'].groupby(df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%B'))['Count'].agg('count')
```

to:

```
df.groupby(df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%B'))['Count'].agg('count')
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pass [series groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html)

```
df.groupby(df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%B'))['Count'].agg('count')
```

If we do series groupby

```
df['Count'].groupby(df["DATE"].dt.strftime('%B')).agg('count')
```